# Delphi 10 Seattle - Failed Android Project Build

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-10-seattle

I am running Delphi 10 Seattle with the Mobile Development Tools.

I have reinstalled the Android Tools/SDK's/NDK multiple times to no avail.

I have never managed to get an android project compiled, i always got various errors, but I've seemed to reach a roadblock with this one :-

I get a total of 1461 when building the project, all are very similar, im putting just 3 below, but will post more if needed.

```
[DCC Error] E2597
C:\Users\Test\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r9c\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: error: cannot find -ldl

C:\Users\Test\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r9c\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: error: cannot find -lc

C:\Users\Test\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r9c\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: error: cannot find -lm
```

And the fatal error :-

```
[DCC Fatal Error] F2588 Linker error code: 1 ($00000001)
```

The project itself is just a Hello World Application to test if building is working, i've seen similar errors when using 3rd party libraries in the application, but no fix seemed to help.

I have double checked all file paths in the SDK Manager, and have posted the filepaths below :-

Android SDK 24.3.3 32 Bit

```
SDK:-

SDK Base Path: C:\Users\Test\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\PlatformSDKs\android-sdk-windows

ZipAlign Location: C:\Users\Test\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\PlatformSDKs\android-sdk-windows\build-tools\22.0.1\ZipAlign.exe

Android Location: C:\Users\Test\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\PlatformSDKs\android-sdk-windows\tools\android.bat

Adb location:
C:\Users\Test\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\PlatformSDKs\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe

Aapt Location:
C:\Users\Test\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\PlatformSDKs\android-sdk-windows\build-tools\25.0.2\aapt.exe

SDK API-Level Location: 
C:\Users\Test\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\PlatformSDKs\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-25

NDK:-

NDK Base Path:
C:\Users\Test\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r9c

arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe Location:
C:\Users\Test\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r9c\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe

arm-linux-androidaebi-strip.exe Location :
C:\Users\Test\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r9c\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-strip.exe

gbdserver Location :
C:\Users\Test\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r9c\prebuilt\android-arm\gdbserver\gdbserver

NDK API Location :
C:\Users\Test\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r9c\platforms\android-19

C++ Builder NDK Library Path:
C:\Users\Test\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r9c\platforms\android-19\arch-arm\usr\lib

Delphi NDK Library Path:
C:\Users\Test\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r9c\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.8\libs\armeabi-v7a

Java:-

Keytool Location:
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin\keytool.exe

Jarsigner Location:
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin\jarsigner.exe
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure how this happened.

But to fix it, I went into the SDK Manager and deleted the entire SDK set and let the installer reinstall it, I had done this previously and had made no changes between attempts, so not sure why it worked, but it did anyway.

I hope this helps someone else.